# Where can I find TF2 Servers that play Freight or Fastlane?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I can't seem to find servers running those maps (except Wonka Gaming, and those are only full of bots all the time). They are two of my favorite maps. When I started playing Team Fortress 2 earlier this year I feel like I saw them a lot more often. Why is that?

I filter my searches, but these days nothing shows up when I do so. I used to search for cp_f to see either Fastlane or Freight (this was before Foundry so it was unlikely to get anything else starting with F) and would always get some results, however, for example I just now tried searching for cp_freight and got only one hit and it had only 6 players. I'm not sure why this is the case lately and I suppose I am wondering if their are either any servers people can recommend that still include these maps, or any reason why the maps have gone into disuse.

Comment: Why don't you filter by map??

Comment: I do filter by map, but even so I do not get more than 2-3 results for either of these maps, and those that I do get are either empty or all bots.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the simple server browser by checking the "Simple server browser" option in the bottom left hand corner. This is kind of broken for me right now, however:

[image]

You can also use the full server browser and filter by map. This is generally more reliable, but you need to know the full map name (e.g. `cp_fastlane`; just "fastlane" won't do):

[image]

Most servers, however, rotate through multiple maps. This is perfectly fine and a good thing. Servers that play the same map 24/7 are more likely to have bots to help people who want a game on that map regardless of time and map, and are more likely to be part of a larger server farm that makes one such server for pretty much every single map out there. Those are hardly conducive to community building.

With no community, you don't have regulars. With no regulars, you don't have donators. Without donators, you don't get money to help offset your hosting costs.

To contradict with the above, however, if you really do positively need to play on a map and there's no such server out there... you can start your own! It isn't rocket science. From the main menu click on the '+' button, pick 'cp_fastlane' or whatever as your map, tweak the settings in the Game map if you need to, make sure you have proper port forwarding in place so people can connect to your server if you're behind a router and - hey presto! You're playing on Fastlane and now you just need... others to join you. Invite your friends or something. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do filter my searches, but these days nothing shows up when I do so. I used to search for cp_f to see either Fastlane or Freight (this was before Foundry so it was unlikely to get anything else starting with F) and would always get some results, however, for example I just now tried searching for cp_freight and got only one hit and it had only 6 players. I'm not sure why this is the case lately and I suppose I am wondering if their are either any servers people can recommend that still include these maps, or any reason why the maps have gone into disuse.

Comment: I will add that detail to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I don't know how you used the "simple server browser" though. I've only used the full server browser. How do you get to the simple version?

Comment: @AppleCor uh... I see at least 99 servers running cp_freight right now, some with players. You might need to doublecheck your other filters.